# Error in fortran module

Tags: fortran

I have created a fortran module with a subroutine and a main program to call that subroutine. But I am getting some errors that I cannot resolve. Can anyone comment? Here is the code:

```
module test
contains
subroutine sub1(array1,a) 
implicit none
real, intent(in) :: array1
integer, intent (in) :: a
integer::temp =1
array1 = (/ (temp, temp=1,a) )
write (*,'(I0)') array1
write (*,*) 'Number of columns = ',a
end subroutine
end module


program p1
use test
implicit none
real,allocatable :: array1 (:,:)
integer :: a =5
allocate (array1(1,a))
call sub1(array1,a)
end program
```

I am getting the following error:

```
array1 = (/ (temp, temp=1,a) )
Error: Syntax error in array constructor at (1)

Fatal Error: Can't open module file 'test.mod' No such file or directory
```

I tried finding some ways, but couldn't figure out what is wrong. Again, comments or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I see several issues, some pointed out by others:

- You've passed `array1` to the subroutine with intent `in` but you change it. Use `intent(out)` or `intent(inout)` (if you initialize parts of it elsewhere)
- `array1` is a 2-dimensional array in `p1` but is declared as a scalar value in `sub1`. Use `array1(:,:)` again in the declaration of `sub1`. Alternatively, you could declare it as `array1(1,a)`.
- The array constructor you are using needs changes:

  - As pointed out by others, you need a `/)` to terminate the constructor
  - `array1` is a 2D array and you are attempting to assign a 1D vector (a series from of 1 to a) to it. Because the size of the first dimension of `array1` is 1, you could use `array1(1,:) =`, which will allow assignment from a 1D array.
  - (A more minor point) `temp` is an integer whereas `array1` is a real. The compiler will automatically convert from integer to real, but it is good to understand what is going on. Thus I recommend using `real(temp)` for your constructor.
- You are writing out `array1` in `sub1` as a single integer (I0); it's a 2D real array. Using `write(*,*)` for both write statements will work.
- You do not need to initialize `temp` to be 1 in `sub1` (thanks @PetrH).

The edited code is then:

```
module test
contains
subroutine sub1(array1,a)
implicit none
real, intent(inout) :: array1(:,:)
integer, intent (in) :: a
integer::temp =1
array1(1,:) = (/ (real(temp), temp=1,a) /)
write (*,*) array1
write (*,*) 'Number of columns = ',a
end subroutine
end module


program p1
use test
implicit none
real,allocatable :: array1 (:,:)
integer :: a =5
allocate (array1(1,a))
call sub1(array1,a)
end program
```

which compiles for me with PGI, giving:

```
1.000000        2.000000        3.000000        4.000000
5.000000
Number of columns =             5
```

Some other thoughts:

- Modules are typically written in their own file. However, if the module appears before the program statement (as you have done here) it will work.
- Why are you declaring `array1` to be 2-dimensional but setting the first dimension to have size 1?
- Instead of passing the size of the second dimension of `array1` as `a` to `sub1`, you could simply access it using `size(array1)`. (thanks @petrH)

Comment: +1 for addressing all other errors in his code. However you have got one yourself, you cannot do `array1(1,:) = ...` as this is not what the original procedure was doing. You need to fill the whole array with `temp` not just the first row. Also the dummy argument `a` is redundant (unless the intention of OP was to fill only a part of the array), it may be worth editing your answer and showing how he can get rid off `a` (using `size(array1)`). Finally in `integer :: temp = 1` the `=1` part is useless.

Comment: @PetrH thanks for the suggestions, I've included the `size` and `temp` initialization.
I'm not sure about the initialization of `array1`: it's dimensioned (1,a) which I assume is known by `sub1`. So I am happy to only initialize the first row of `array1`.

Comment: It is initialized outside the procedure and the procedure has to work with everything of shape 2 which is passed in it. What if `array1` is allocated as `allocate (array1(2,a))`? Your procedure will only fill the first row, which is not what the OP intended (most likely).

Answer (score 0):

According to some [array constructors](http://h21007.www2.hp.com/portal/download/files/unprot/fortran/docs/lrm/lrm0056.htm) documentation I found with google, the following line is incorrect:

```
array1 = (/ (temp, temp=1,a) )
```

and should probably be

```
array1 = (/ (temp, temp=1,a) /)
```

Answer (score 0):

And you have to put your module in a separate file `test.f90`.
Also you will then get an error that you have a Dummy argument with INTENT(IN) in variable definition context.

I think this is because you are changing your Input array. Try to assign a dummy like `array2 = array1`

Last but not least the line `array2=(/ (temp,temp=1,a) /)` (this has to be changed to this like Greg said) states a rank 2 array, array1 is only a rank 1 array.

Comment: You do NOT have to put the module in a separeta file. Small modules in the same file are very useful!

Comment: you dont have to right, but on my compiler it only worked when it was in two different files...

Comment: @Fl.pf. What is your compiler? On my ifort 14 it worked from a single file and it has to work in any compiler adhering to the standard.

Comment: I use Code::Blocks with Gnu Fortran Compiler. Has to be something with the Comp. because I also cant execute the program because of a `Expected PARAMETER symbol in complex constant` bug, which I read is a syntax error. But i even have that error with the example from Ross' answer